# laravel, How to update array in json column?

Tags: laravel

in my Laravel app, the database has a column named "mavads" as :

```
{
  "en": [
    {
      "need": "enn1",
      "amount": "enm1"
    },
    {
      "need": "enn2",
      "amount": "enm2"
    },
    {
      "need": "enn3",
      "amount": "enm3"
    },
  ],
  "ru": [
    {
      "need": "run1",
      "amount": "rum1"
    },
    {
      "need": "run2",
      "amount": "rum1"
    },
  ]
}
```

This is the form that send data as PUT to the controller to update the database:

```
@foreach($food->mavads['en'] as $m)
      <input type="text" class="input" name="enneed[]" value="{{ $m['need'] }}">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="enamount[]" value="{{ $m['amount'] }}">
@endforeach

@foreach($food->mavads['ru'] as $m)
      <input type="text" class="input" name="runeed[]" value="{{ $m['need'] }}">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="ruamount[]" value="{{ $m['amount'] }}">
@endforeach
```

the Food Model:

```
  protected $casts = [
    'mavads' => 'array'
  ];
```

in Controller, I get $request and want to update each { "need": "run2","amount": "rum1"} of en or ru languages:

```
    $enmavad = $request->only('enneed', 'enamount');
    $rumavad = $request->only('runeed', 'ruamount');
    $food->mavads = ["en" => $enmavad, "ru" => $rumavad];

but I get the error and no correct update
```

Comment: what error does it occur?

Comment: { "en":[ "....", "...."] } .... instead of { "en": [ {"need": "......", "amount" : " ..... "} ] }

Comment: plz post the value of `$enmavad`

Comment: $enmavad = $request->only('enneed', 'enamaount');
return $enmavad;
    {"enneed":["en need 1","en need 2"],"enamount":["en amount 1","en amount 2"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
@foreach($food->mavads['en'] as $m)
      <input type="text" class="input" name="enneed[]" value="{{ $m['need'] }}">
      <input type="text" class="input" name="enamount[]" value="{{ $m['amount'] }}">
@endforeach
```

When you submit, the values will be wrap in array for the key `enneed` and `enamount`, look like this:

```php
[
  'enneed' => ['enn1', 'enn2'],
  'enamount' => ['enm1', 'enm2']
]
```

So you can change your html to be like this:

```html
@foreach($food->mavads['en'] as $i => $m)
      <input type="text" class="input" name={{"en[$i][need]"}} value="{{ $m['need'] }}">
      <input type="text" class="input" name={{"en[$i][amount]"}} value="{{ $m['amount'] }}">
@endforeach
```

It will return:

```php
[
  'en' =>[[
    'need' => 'enn1',
    'amount' => 'emn1'
  ],[
    'need' => 'enn2',
    'amount' => 'emn2'
  ]],
]
```

So in your controller, you can directly get the data format:

```php
    $enmavad = $request->only('en');
    $rumavad = $request->only('ru');
    $food->mavads = array_merge($enmavad, $rumavad);
```

Comment: thank you for time and help but I get this in database adn error"

```
{
  "en": {
    "en": [
      {
        "'need'": "en need 1",
        "'amount'": "en amount 1"
      },
      {
        "'need'": "en need 2",
        "'amount'": "en amount 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ru": {
    "ru": {
      "1": {
        "'need'": "ru need 2",
        "'amount'": "ru amount 2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: everything seems ok except this single quests :
{"en":[{" 'need' " .... which makes an error in reading from column data

Comment: @MehdiYaghoubi sorry for the single quote, I have removed it.

Comment: thank you friend for all help and guide. you art great. wish you the best and health.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209633/discussion-between-mehdi-yaghoubi-and-tsaikoga).